# How to deal with API call from website and consequently show information belonging to the website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api-design

In my Ruby on Rails app, bike rental companies can manage all their bikes (reservations, payments etc.).

**Goal**

I would like to offer a bike rental companies the option to implement a booking form on their own website, so they can let customers create a reservation for a specific bike.

This booking form would then take available bikes from my Rails app to their website and consequently send new reservation data back to the Rails app.

**Question**

How can I link the website of a shop, to a specific `Shop` within my application. Thereby, making sure a specific website indeed should be able to GET information belonging to a `Shop`.

***Code***

models

```
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bike_categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :bikes, through: :bike_categories
  has_many :user_shops, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_shops
  has_many :reservations, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: ->(attrs) { attrs['email'].blank? || attrs['role'].blank?}
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_shops, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :shops, through: :user_shops
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_shops
  enum role: [:owner, :admin, :employee, :accountant, :demo, :app_owner]
end

class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop
  belongs_to :bike
end
```

controllers/api/v1/reservations_controller

```
  def create
    # How to know/specify which shop?
    @shop = Shop.new(shop_params)
    authorize @shop
    if @shop.save
      render :show, status: :created
    else
      render_error
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your textbook example of a [nested resource](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources). In REST a nested resouces is nested in the path of another resource:

```
/authors/1/books
/countries/uk/cities
/blogs/1/posts/2
```

The genius here is that the path itself describes the relation between the resources.

You can make the route nested by passing a block to `resources`:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :shops do 
      resources :reservations, shallow: true
    end
  end
end
```

The `shallow` option makes only the collection routes nested (new, create, index) which is usually a good thing since records have a unique id anyways which they can be fetched through.

`/blogs/1/posts/2` is an example of deeply nested route. If the id is unique we should be able to get the exact same resource through `/posts/2` which simplefies the code greatly as it does not need to know about the `blog`.

```
module API
  module V1
    class ReservationsController < ApiController
      before_action :set_shop, only: [:create, :index]

      # GET /api/v1/shops/1/resevations
      def index
        @reservations = @shop.reservations
      end 

      # POST/api/v1/shops/1/resevations
      def create
        @reservation = @shop.reservations.new(reservation_params)
        # ...
      end

      # ...
      private

      def set_shop
         @shop = Shop.includes(:reservations).find(params[:shop_id])
      end

      # ...
    end
  end
end
```